# Navigate to area of Markdown file in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

I have a markdown file with a number of codes and descriptions within it which will be used like a wiki.

A developer will be given a link, and the link should take them to the specific code within the markdown file.

Example of file:

```
#IAmAPizza
This declares that you are a pizza
#CordialComrade
You've encountered a cordial comrade who will eat your pizza.
...
#ZestfulZebra
You can't keep up with him, just go with it.
[test code](#test-code)
I am a testing code
```

I've tried navigating to the file in the repo and then adding `#test-code` to the address, but it doesn't do anything.  I assume that the markdown isn't being rendered on the page.

Is there a way to navigate to a specific # within a file in an Azure Devops Repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to navigate to a specific # within a file in an Azure Devops Repo?

We could try to open the markdown file in the repo under the Contents view. Then select the specific #, like: `#ZestfulZebra`:

[image]

Just as Hugh pointed, there is an option **copy link to this selection**. We could get the link after click the hyperlink symbol, it should be:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_git/<ProjectName>?path=%2FReadme.md&version=GBmaster&line=64&lineEnd=64&lineStartColumn=1&lineEndColumn=14&lineStyle=plain
```

And the link for the markdown file is:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_git/<ProjectName>?path=%2FReadme.md&version=GBmaster
```

So, it use the syntax `&line=64&lineEnd=64&lineStartColumn=1&lineEndColumn=14&lineStyle=plain` to locate the anchor we selected.

Now, we can simply parse this syntax `&line=64&lineEnd=64` is used to locate the line number we select the code. If we change it to `&line=64&lineEnd=65`, it will select the lines `64` and `65`. And the `&lineStartColumn=1&lineEndColumn=14` is used to locate the start and end positions of the selected string.

Now, we could use this syntax with the link of markdown file to navigate to a specific # within a file in an Azure Devops Repo.

For example, we could use the web address to navigate the anchors in the MD:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_git/<ProjectName>?path=%2FReadme.md&version=GBmaster&line=64&lineEnd=64&lineStartColumn=1&lineEndColumn=14&lineStyle=plain
```

Comment: In order to use this approach, I'd need to know the line numbers in an MD file in Azure from my application at runtime.   However, when I tried "Copy link to selection" in the MD file it showed a `anchor=zestfulzebra` at the end of the uri, which is ultimately what I was looking for.  Thanks to @Leo and @Hugh for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean adding anchor link in markdown file? If so, I tested this syntax: `[test](codeLink)` without `#` and it works well.

I first get the code link in a code file in the repo:

[image]

Then add this:`[test](https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_git/{repo}?path=%2FStartup.cs&version=GBmaster&line=4&lineEnd=5&lineStartColumn=1&lineEndColumn=1&lineStyle=plain)` to markdown file:

[image]

Click `test` in the wiki to successfully navigate to the code:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, but that's not quite what I was going for.  I'm looking to create anchors in the MD file that I can navigate to via a web address. Not link from the MD file to a piece of code.

Comment: Through `copy link to this selection` , we can get the web address .For example: `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_git/{repoName}?path=%2FProperties%2FforTest.md&version=GBmaster&line=14&lineEnd=14&lineStartColumn=1&lineEndColumn=14&lineStyle=plain`